# Сообщение от пользователя telegram на python?

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

недавно у меня появилась проблема никак не могу ее решить, мне нужно получить сообщение от юзера, но при каждом его выводе в cmd вижу не сообщение от юзера, а сообщение написанное ботом, пробовал получать сообщения в пустом дискрипторе, но он все равно выводил не то что нужно

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(cb.filter(type='categoryadd'))
async def spis(call: CallbackQuery, callback_data: dict):
    data = await db.get_product_id()
    for i in data:
        print(i[0])
        insert_product_id = int(i[0]) + 1
    category_id = callback_data.get('category_id')
    keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    keyboard.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text='добавить позицию',callback_data='btn:add_price:-:-'))
    await bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,'напишите через пробел позицию пример (название цена колличество)',reply_markup=keyboard)

    time.sleep(10)
    string = call.message.text
    print(string)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы запрашиваете сообщение от пользователя и хотите выводить его после получения, то можно использовать функцию `register_next_step_handler`, в которую надо передать сообщение бота и следующую функцию, которая будет обрабатывать полученное сообщение от пользователя. В telebot это будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
import telebot
from telebot import types


dp = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

@dp.message_handler(commands=['message'])
def msg_from_user1(message: types.Message):
    msg = dp.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите сообщение...')
    dp.register_next_step_handler(msg, msg_from_user2)

def msg_from_user2(message: types.Message):
    msg_from_user = message.text
    print(msg_from_user)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    dp.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Здесь, после отправки команды */message* боту, он будет запрашивать сообщение от пользователя и после его получения запустит функцию `msg_from_user2`, которая выведет это сообщение в консоль.
В aiogram вроде не работает.

Comment: в aiogram нету такого метода, но суть я понял, спасибо